# Riemann-Stieltjies integral. Find total variation.

Tags: total-variation

I need to find the total variation of $V_g([0,2\pi])$, when $g(x)=cos(x)$

According to the formula:
$V_g([a,b])=g(b)-g(a)$

$V_g([0,2\pi])=cos(2\pi)-cos(0)=1-1=0$

But this answer is shown as wrong. What is wrong there?

Comment: Your formula is wrong.

Comment: This formula $V_g([a,b])=g(b)−g(a)$ ?

Comment: The formula you have is valid for monotonic increasing functions: if you check your source it will probably state this as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is wrong and so is the anwser!. Since $\cos 0=1$ and $\cos \pi =-1$ there is no way the total variation can be $1$ (because $|\cos 0-\cos \pi|=2$). The correct formula is $V_g=\int_0^{\pi} |g'(x)|\, dx$ which is $4.$

Comment: I fixed the original question. In my question I had $cos(2\pi)$ not $cos(\pi)$, so your answer can also be erroneous.

Comment: My answer is correct. The total variation of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is $f(b)-f(a)$ if $f$ is an increasing function. Since $\cos x$ is not increasing on $[0,2\pi]$ you cannot use  this formula.

Comment: When  I said that the total variation cannot be $1$ I used the fact that $|f(y)-f(x)| \leq V_g$  for any two points $x$ and $y$. I chose $x=0$ and $y=\pi$ which are points in the given interval. What I can  conclude from this is $V_g \geq 2$.